# JAVA Client server backup Logic

Tags: java, client-server, backup-strategies

I have created a java code for performing a file, folder structure backup on the server. Now the code is working perfectly. The code looks into a specified directory and monitors changes made to files and creates a compressed backup.

So on a first time run , the code backs up all the files and folders. The consecutive times it makes a compressed backup of only the changed files / folders.

Currently the backup runs only when the client side program initiates a request.
I made the backup script run on the server as a cron job now. It creates the compressed backup files each  time it finds a difference in files. Each file is named as "OTA_[some_id]_[backup-timestamp]" .

I'm stuck at figuring out on how to make sure that the client syncs with the current data and doesn't need to re-sync the already synced compressed backup files.

NOTE: The client and server might not be running in the same timezones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UTC or GMT for your timestamp so that it doesn't matter which timezones your client and server are in.

Comment: Hmm...that worked...but I finally ended up creating a version control system to do that..